# Clicking a certain coord on a certain Window at a certain rate

Tags: autohotkey

I simply want an autohotkey script that will click and xy location (say 0,0) of my choosing at a certain rate (say every 4 minutes) on a certain window, say 'Window1'.

How would I create this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to click at a specific place *inside* of a window (so that it doesn't matter where the window is)? Or do you want it to always click the same place on your desktop? [AHK Help - CoordMode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm)

I would make a hotkey to turn on/off the click sub, using [SetTimer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) to do the clicking.

```
f1:: ;;; change this to suit
If ( bT := !bT )
    SetTimer , l_Timer , 2000 ;;; milliseconds, 4 min. = 240000 ms
Else
    SetTimer , l_timer , Off
Return

l_Timer:
If WinExist( "Window 1" ) ;;; change to title of window (case-sensitive) to click
{
;   CoordMode , Mouse , Screen ;;; uncomment if using absolute coords
    MouseGetPos , nX , nY
    WinGetTitle , sActive , A
    WinActivate , Window 1 ;;; change to title of window (case-sensitive) to click
    MouseClick ,, 100 , 100 ;;; change coordinates to suit
    WinActivate , %sActive%
    MouseMove , nX , nY
}
Return
```